Proving that $\iint f(x) g(x+y) dx dy \leq \int g^2(x) dx$
Let $D \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be bounded, and $f,g: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Furthermore let $f$ be nonnegative and such that $\int_D f dx= 1$.
I would like to prove that
$$\int_D \int_D f(x)g^2(x+y)dxdy \leq \int_D g^2(y).$$
My attempt has been to use the fact that $\int_D f dx = 1$ to define a new measure $df = fdx$ which is now a probability measure, and then to use Jensen's inequality but that doesn't seem to get very far. The biggest obstacle for me has been going from $g(x+y)$ to $g(y)$ in the integral.
Any tips on how I can proceed?
EDIT: Based on the counter-example given by Matt Werenski and the comment given by Raghav,  I will strengthen the assumptions by requiring $f \in C^\infty(D)$ and that the support of $f$ is strictly contained within the support of $g$.
EDIT 2: Based on more comments and the answer by Julio Puerta, it seems I need the support of $g$ to be contained in $D$, so I will assume this as well.

The counterexample by Matt Werenski can be easily modified so that $f\in C^{\infty}(D)$. The thrust of the counterexample comes from the fact that the support of $g$ does not intersect with $D$ and this makes the RHS in your desired inequality $0$. While the left hand side is non-zero if the support of $g$ is not too far from $D$.

@Raghav I see, thank you for your comment. Maybe I can try to place certain restrictions on the supports. For example, if I assume the support of $f$ is strictly contained within the support of $g$.

Note that $\int_{D}\int_{D}f(x)g^2(x+y);dx;dy\leq \int_{D}f(x);dx\left(\int_{D+x}g^2(y);dy\right)$. Since $f(x)1_{x\in D}$ is a probability density, what you want is $\int_{D+x}g^2(y);dy\leq \int_{D}g(y); dy$ for a.e. $x$. (This is not a necessary condition but a sufficient one.) The easiest way to obtain this would be to assume that support of $g$ is contained in $D$.

@Raghav Thank you. I am indeed assuming support of $g$ is contained in $D$ so that $\int_{D+x}g^2(y);dy = \int_{D}g^2(y);dy$. I assume the result then follows from the first inequality you gave. How did you obtain this inequality aside from the change of variables?

This can not be true in general because the integral on the right-hand side gives equal weight to all points of $D$, but the function $f$ on the left-hand side can be modified to give weight to the places where $g$ is biggest.

If you assume that the support of $g$ is contained in $D$, then the inequality follows from a simple re-arrangement. Observe that
$$\int_{D}\int_{D}f(x)g^2(x+y)\;dx\;dy= \int_{D}\left(\int_{D}g^2(x+y)\;dy\right)f(x)\;dx.$$
The order of integral does not matter in this case as $f$ and $g^2$ are both non-negative and hence we can apply Tonelli's theorem.
Now, let's consider the integral $G(x):= \int_{D}g^2(x+y)dy$. Here, use a change of variable and the fact that the support of $g$ is contained in $g$ to argue that $G(x)\leq \int_{D}g^2(y)dy$. In more detail,
$$G(x)= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}g^2(x+y)1_{D}(y)dy=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}g^2(y)1_{D}(y-x)dy,$$
where the last equality uses the translation invariance of Lebesgue measure. Now use the fact that $1_{D}(y-x)\leq 1$ for all $x, y$ to obtain that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}g^2(y)1_{D}(y-x)dy\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}g^2(y)dy =\int_{D}g^2(y)dy.$$
The inequality above used the simple $L^1-L^{\infty}$ bound if you want to be pedantic and last equality follows from the fact that the support of $g$ is in $D$.
Putting it all back in the first display, we get
$$\int_{D}\int_{D}\left(\int_{D}g^2(x+y)dy\right)f(x)dx\leq \int_{D}f(x)dx\int_{D}g^2(y)dy.$$
The conclusion follows by noting that $\int_{D}f(x)dx=1$.
Most of the above details are unnecessary. The only thing that matters is that for each $x$, $\int_{D+x}g(y)dy= \int_{D+x\cap D}g(y)dy\leq \int_{D}g(y)dy$. The first equality because $g$ is only supported inside $D$, so you may replace $g(y)$ by $g(y)1_{D}(y)$.

Thank you very much for all your help!

The claim as written is not in general true. A counterexample comes from
$$D = B(0,1)$$
$$f = \frac{1}{\text{Vol}(B(0,1))}\pmb{1}[x \in B(0,1)]$$
$$g = \pmb{1}[x \notin B(0,1)]$$
In this case
$$\int_D g^2(x)dx = 0$$
and
$$\int_D\int_D f(x)g^2(x+y)dx dy > 0$$
which goes the opposite direction of the claim.

Thank you for this counterexample. I wonder if requiring $f \in C^\infty(D)$ rules out similar counterexamples and makes the claim true.

Following the edit of the question, a counterexample with both $f,g\in C^{\infty}(D)$
and the support of $f$ being contained in the support of g is as follows: $$f\equiv 1\\g(x)=e^x\\D=[0,1]$$
We clearly have $\displaystyle\int_D f(x)\,dx=1$ and $\operatorname{Sop}(f)=\mathbb{R}=\operatorname{Sop}(g)$.
Nonetheless, $$\int_D \int_D f(x)g^2(x+y)\,dx\,dy=\int_D \int_D e^{2x+2y}\,dx\,dy=\dfrac{(e^2-1)^2}{4} >\dfrac{e^2-1}{2}\\=\int_D e^{2y}\,dy= \int_D g^2(y)$$
If one wanted the support of $f$ to be strictly contained on the support of $g$, one could simply replace $f$ by a bump function that is equal to $1$ on $D$ and is $0$ from some point onwards.
Furthermore, there is no reason to believe the result is true even if we strengthen the hypothesis, because the $x+y$ term on the integral takes on values outside of $D$, where $g$ can be much larger than it is on $D$ (such as the exponential on the above example).

Thank you for your answer. Thanks to Raghav's help in the comments I am requiring that the support of $g$ is contained in $D$. Would this be enough for the result to hold?

@CBBAM There is no reason to believe that the result is true, even in that case.
